# How can I use a variable in a multiline string in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, string-interpolation, multilinestring, delphi-12-athens

[Delphi 12 introduced multiline strings](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/yukon-beta-blog-delphi-language-modernizing-string-literals/#Multiline_Strings) and I'm trying to figure out how it works, coming from a JavaScript background. There I can directly have variables in multiline strings such as:

```
const myName = 'Martin';
const myString = `Hi ${myName},
Say hello to 
multi-line
strings!`;
```

And that would replace `${myName}` with the content of the variable. How can this be achieved in Delphi with the new `'''` multiline Strings?

Comment: Delphi doesn't support this. The Format function can be used instead.

Comment: Rule of thumb is: scripting languages are able to do this (because the code is interpreted every iteration anew), programming languages not (code is compiled once). Other notable scripting languages supporting this are Perl and PHP.

Comment: Mentioning "multiline strings" seems to be irrelevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi does not support [String interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation), as some languages do, like Java, C#, etc.  The new multi-line syntax simply allows a string literal to span across line breaks, nothing more.

To do what you want, you would still need to use plain string concatenation, e.g.:

```
const myName = 'Martin';
const myString = 'Hi ' + myName +
'''
,
Say hello to 
multi-line
strings!
''';
```

The closest thing that Delphi has to String interpolation is [`SysUtils.Format()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.Format), e.g.:

```
const myName = 'Martin';
const myString = Format(
'''
Hi %s,
Say hello to 
multi-line
strings!
''',
[myName]);
```

Comment: Which is Delphi's variant of C's [`printf()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf).

Comment: @AmigoJack `System.Write/Ln()` with `SysUtils.Format()`

Comment: You might want to emphasize that your code shows an inline immutable variable declaration and not a const declaration because otherwise one might be confused about the usage of `Format` with a `const`.